# Angular5: innerHtml binding does not work without sanitization

Tags: angular

I have a hybrid angular 5 app (angularJS + angular5).

The following code prints no text on the browser document,

Component:

```
user.description = "some text"
```

Template:

```
<p [innerHtml]="user.description"><p>
```

However, following works correctly,

Component:

```
// sanitizer is injected DomSanitizer service
user.description = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("some text");
```

Template:

```
<p [innerHtml]="user.description"><p>
```

I tried to reproduce the problem in Stackblitz but unfortunately I can not. But I have the same issue on another hybrid angular app too.

Has anyone come across similar issue? This is driving me nuts and have hard time using third party UI components which use innerHtml.

Comment: There is no way around binding to innerHtml without sanitizing. If all you want to do is display text though, then use your template `{{user.description}}`

Comment: @Zze I disagree. Please see this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-innerhtml-click. It is not necessary to sanitize a text to bind to innerHtml. Also, I can always sanitize the text with in my code to come around the problem. But I am also using third party components which does innerHtml binding without sanitization